# What are all the ways to regenerate Action Points?

Tags: die2nite

The Die2Nite wiki is still very incomplete, and the [article on Action Points](http://die2nite.wikia.com/wiki/Action_Points) only mentions:

- Food
- Water

Both of which recharge your AP completely and can be used once per day for this purpose.  However, I know there are other ways to recharge AP, like drugs.  Can someone provide the full list of ways to recharge your AP.  Please also list any additional benefits or disadvantages for each (e.g. drugs get you addicted).

Comment: Try this wiki: http://d2nwiki.com/wiki/Action_Points

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So far, I know of the following:

- **Water.** This only works once per day.
- **Food.** This only works once per day. (Note, that some food, such as a Meaty Bone can cause an Infection which could get you killed!)
- **Drugs.** Most drugs will restore AP to full, however, while under the influence, your forum posts will be affected, and there is a chance of addiction. Once you are addicted, if you do not take drugs every day, you will die.
- **Alcohol.** This only works once per day. Drinking will refill your AP gauge, but it will inhibit your ability to perform some tasks, including searching, combat, and posting to the forum. The day after drinking, you will be hungover and unable to consume alcohol.
- **EMS System.** This can only be used if you are not injured. Consumes 1 Battery, restores AP to 5, and instantly injures you.
- **Dice.** Can be used once per day, small chance to restore 1 AP via scales and triples.
- **Cards.** Can be used once per day, small chance to restore 1 AP via aces and queen of hearts, smaller chance of terrifying you.
- **Siesta Time™** (hero only). The basic version of this house improvement gives you a daily 33% chance of recovering 2 AP per day.

Comment: Do food and water restore all 6 action points?

Comment: Yes, however, if you are not at 0 action points, they will *only* bring you up to a maximum of 6! Do not use food/water until you are out of AP. Additionally, some foods, such as Juicy Steak, will provide +1 Bonus AP, leaving you at 7/6.

Comment: not being able to consume alcohol while hungover is completely unrealistic.

Comment: what about playing cards?

Comment: @Gnome Cards can give AP too, but they can also terrify you. @Less Dice do not award AP on doubles, but on special rolls like straights.

Answer (score 5):

Playing cards can also give 0, 1 or 2 AP.

Answer (score 5):

Coffee can give 4 AP and can be used multiple times on the same day with no negative effects.

Also I've used Siesta a few times and I always got 2 AP.

Answer (score 4):

The Siesta upgrade for Hero homes can let you take a nap for a few AP (I've heard 3, but not exactly sure on the specifics).

Answer (score 0):

It is only when someone plays the Makeshift Guitar, usable once per day. If you are in town and drunk or drugged, you restore 2 AP. Othwerise, you only restore 1 AP.